Chvatal-Gomory integer rounding method to find facets of $\operatorname{conv}(S)$
The question:
"given a set $S = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : 4x_1 + x_2 ≤ 28, x_1 + 4x_2 ≤ 27, x_1 − x_2 ≤ 1, x ≥ 0 \}$.
we are tasked with deriving each facet of $\operatorname{conv}(S)$ as a Chvatal-Gomory inequality (from the existing inequalities in the description of $S$)."
Now, given this set, we can see that the facets for $\operatorname{conv}(S)$ are $$x_1+2x_2≤15,x_1-x_2≤1,x_1≤5,x_2≤6,x≥0$$
I'm having trouble deriving the inequality $x_1+2x_2≤15$ using only the C-G rounding method.
from the theorems in the book "Integer and Combinatorial Optimization" it seems that I should be able to derive all of the facets for $\operatorname{conv}(S)$, but I just can't find a way to do so, it seems impossible.
Multiple rounds of the C-G rounding method are okay, as they are considered part of the method like in this case
would appreciate any help with this, answers or insights about how to "aim" and reach a certain inequality using the method.

Have you checked the coefficients of all three original inequalities and the one you cannot derive? Could there be a typo?

hey, thanks for the reply, while there might be a problem with the question, which defines the set S, the derived facets of conv(S) were reached by me, as the extreme points of the set are (0,0) (0,6) (3,6) (5,5) (5,4) (1,0), and the equation I'm trying to find is a by product of that. I've edited the post and added quotes to show the information given in the question

Those extreme points and facets look correct.  Not all C-G inequalities can be derived in one round (C-G rank 1), so maybe try to derive it in two rounds (C-G rank 2) from a combination of the original inequalities and other C-G inequalities.

I've been trying different combinations but to no avail, I don't know if I'm missing some sort of intuition or strategy here, it feels impossible. i thought maybe there is some kind of structure to the madness or some way to aim towards that facet that I'm just missing.
thank you for reassuring the other points though, at this point anything helps.

Your target constraint cannot be derived from the original constraints (only) via C-G cuts. That's provable. So Either multiple rounds are needed or there is something off with the question.

Multiple rounds are okay, as they are part of the C-G rounding method. but even then, I cant find the right "path" and combinations using the method in order to reach the desired inequality. I'm sorry if this was not clear enough i shall edit the post.

Here's a systematic approach that uses LP duality.  First write your constraints as \begin{align}
4x_1 + x_2 &\le 28 \tag1\label1\\
x_1 + 4x_2 &\le 27 \tag2\label2\\
x_1 - x_2  &\le 1 \tag3\label3\\
-x_1       &\le 0 \tag4\label4\\
-x_2       &\le 0 \tag5\label5
\end{align}
To derive $x_1 \le 5$, maximize $x_1$ subject to \eqref{1} through \eqref{5}, yielding $x_1=29/5$, with dual solution $\pi=(1/5, 0, 1/5, 0, 0)$.  Multiplying the constraints by $\pi$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{5}(4x_1 + x_2) + \frac{1}{5}(x_1 - x_2) &\le \frac{1}{5}(28) + \frac{1}{5}(1) \\
x_1 &\le \frac{29}{5} \\
x_1 &\le \left\lfloor\frac{29}{5}\right\rfloor \\
x_1 &\le 5 \tag6\label6
\end{align}
To derive $x_2 \le 6$, maximize $x_2$ subject to \eqref{1} through \eqref{5}, yielding $x_2=27/4$, with dual solution $\pi=(0, 1/4, 0, 1/4, 0)$.  Multiplying the constraints by $\pi$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}(x_1 + 4x_2) + \frac{1}{4}(-x_1) &\le \frac{1}{4}(27) + \frac{1}{4}(0) \\
x_2 &\le \frac{27}{4} \\
x_2 &\le \left\lfloor\frac{27}{4}\right\rfloor \\
x_2 &\le 6 \tag7\label7
\end{align}
To derive $x_1 + 2x_2 \le 15$, maximize $x_1 + 2x_2$ subject to \eqref{1} through \eqref{5}, yielding $x=(17/3,16/3)$ with $x_1 + 2x_2 = 49/3$ and dual solution $\pi=(2/15, 7/15, 0, 0, 0)$.  Multiplying the constraints by $\pi$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{15}(4x_1 + x_2) + \frac{7}{15}(x_1 + 4x_2) &\le \frac{2}{15}(28) + \frac{7}{15}(27) \\
x_1 + 2x_2 &\le \frac{49}{3} \\
x_1 + 2x_2 &\le \left\lfloor\frac{49}{3}\right\rfloor \\
x_1 + 2x_2 &\le 16 \tag8\label8
\end{align}
That's almost what we want, but the RHS is $16$ instead of $15$.
We want to find nonnegative dual multipliers $(\pi_1,\dots,\pi_8)$ such that
\begin{align}
1 &\le 4\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3-\pi_4+\pi_6+\pi_8 < 2 \\
2 &\le \pi_1+4\pi_2-\pi_3-\pi_5+\pi_7+2\pi_8 < 3 \\
15 &\le 28\pi_1+27\pi_2+\pi_3+5\pi_6+6\pi_7+16\pi_8 < 16
\end{align}
But this is infeasible, so you will need another round of C-G cuts.

Here's one way to finish things off, where the dual multipliers are obtained from the fractional parts of the slack variable coefficients in the simplex tableau.  First take   $\pi_6=\pi_8=1/2$, yielding
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}(x_1) + \frac{1}{2}(x_1 + 2x_2) &\le \frac{1}{2}(5) + \frac{1}{2}(16) \\
x_1 + x_2 &\le \frac{21}{2} \\
x_1 + x_2 &\le \left\lfloor\frac{21}{2}\right\rfloor \\
x_1 + x_2 &\le 10 \tag9\label9
\end{align}
Now take
$\pi_2=1/3$ and $\pi_9=2/3$, yielding
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3}(x_1+4x_2) + \frac{2}{3}(x_1 + x_2) &\le \frac{1}{3}(27) + \frac{2}{3}(10) \\
x_1 + 2x_2 &\le \frac{47}{3} \\
x_1 + 2x_2 &\le \left\lfloor\frac{47}{3}\right\rfloor \\
x_1 + 2x_2 &\le 15 \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{align}

interesting, I was doing something very similar but without rhyme or reason. I will give it a shot next time i have some free time and close this post afterwards. thank you very much!
